# Is there a way to identify a Facebook user without storing his/hers Facebook ID or email address?

Tags: facebook

Assume an service which stores confidential information linked to individual users. Along with this confidential information also things like age, gender and location are stored about each user.

A system like this could be nicely implemented using Facebook Connect. Users wouldn't have to fill out all the required information and the registration process would be very simple.

To identify the user the next time it uses the service his/hers Facebook ID or email address should be stored. But then, if the system were ever to be breached, all the confidential information could be linked to people their Facebook ID or email address.

Is there a way to obtain an unique identifier from the Facebook API, which can only be obtained by your own Facebook application and isn't otherwise traceable back to an user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to obtain an unique identifier from the Facebook API

Yes, there is – it’s the field called `third_party_id` on the [Graph API user object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) (and on the corresponding [FQL user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) as well).

> which can only be obtained by your own Facebook application and isn't otherwise traceable back to an user?

Yes, this `third_party_id` is specific for every app. Even if someone else got it into their hands, they would not be able to find out who the user is – **unless**, of course, they get control over your app too (so that they could look up the user using your app’s credentials).